# Getting error with pandas data reader when looking up stock with a period in the ticker

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Getting an error when running this code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = dt.datetime(2018,12,1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
df = web.DataReader('brk.b', 'yahoo', start, end)

print(df)
```

I get a "Key error: 'Date'"

That's the only stock in the SP 500 that isn't strictly letters and so my program won't run.  All other stocks that only have letters in their tickers work just fine.  I added a try/except to skip this stock but I want to know why it's happening and how I can fix, if possible.  Thanks in advance

**Edit: Figured out a workaround that works, here's the edit:**

change:

```
'brk.b'
```

to:

```
'brk.b'.replace('.','-')
```

With replace, if you have a big list of tickers, you can just call your list, use replace to swap periods to dashes and it should be able to fetch the data for that company

Comment: please provide more code.

Comment: That is the entire code.  Anyway, I figured out a workaround that works perfectly.  I'll edit the OP

Answer (score 3):

Based on this information: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/282. There are several stocks that had to manually add '-' (or replace '.' with '-') to get working with Yahoo, such as BF-B, BRK-B, FCE-A, JW-A, LGF-A, LGF-B, PBR-A, RDS-A, RDS-B.

Hope this can help you.